# Chrome extension using Unsplash API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Hello I've developed chrome extension named [airdesk](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/airdesk/gheeojjcdeaefjjpploghdjpnbhanibe?hl=ko).

We using Unsplash image upload into extension file. It's fast way but these images are too large and bad way to show. I hope to integrate Unsplash API but it seems like requiring server. Of course, we can use simply get image from source.unsplash embedded style. But I think this way is also bad.

Is it possible to get data using only client side code? How can '[momentum](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/momentum/laookkfknpbbblfpciffpaejjkokdgca?hl=ko)'(this is also chrome extension)do?

Comment: Please make your header more relevant to the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use chrome storage to store images you get from Unsplash API. and then load it from storage. So only first time you load it will be slow.

Comment: Thanks a lot Darko Vucetic. I would try this.